# Is there any class to convert AbRecordRef into vcard or NSData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

Do anyone know of an open source class/library that will let you convert an ABRecordRef into vcard or NSData for saving in Core Data. Saving the RecordID won't do it for me since I don't wish to save the contact in the address book.

Answer (score 1):

try out the edited [ABContactHelper](https://github.com/carlj/ABContactHelper) with a vCard Class!

Answer (score -1):

Search vCardRepresentation in the apple docs